# Как отключить пагинацию в elasticsearch

Tags: java, kotlin, elasticsearch

Создаю запрос в elasticsearch через NativeSearchQueryBuilder(), но ответ приходит мне в форме страниц, т.е. 10 записей.

Вопрос: **Как отключить пагинацию с помощью builder'ов elasticsearch?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно принудительно переопределить параметры From и Size, которые отвечают за постраничную навигацию, необходимыми Вам значениями.

Например так (из документации):

```
SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch("index1", "index2")
    .setSearchType(SearchType.DFS_QUERY_THEN_FETCH)
    .setQuery(QueryBuilders.termQuery("multi", "test"))                 // Query
    .setPostFilter(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("age").from(12).to(18))     // Filter
    .setFrom(0).setSize(60).setExplain(true)
    .get();
```

Подробнее в документации: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/7.x/java-search.html

Comment: Спасибо, но это не совсем то, Уточнил в вопросе как создаю запрос

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл метод .size()

У меня теперь так:

```
val query = NativeSearchQueryBuilder()
            .withSearchType(SearchType.DEFAULT)
            .withIndices("task_elastic")
            .addAggregation(AggregationBuilders
                    .terms("city")
                    .field("city").size(Int.MAX_VALUE))
            .build()
```

Видимо этот метод есть и у `term`, и у подобных методов